# Extract FieldType key and value from HList

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless

I would like to extract the key and value of the head of an `HList` using these two methods:

```
def getFieldName[K, V](value: FieldType[K, V])(implicit witness: Witness.Aux[K]): K = witness.value
def getFieldValue[K, V](value: FieldType[K, V]): V = value
```

I tried a few variations of this function, but I couldn't make it work, I think this might be the closest to the right solution:

```
def getFieldNameValue[Key <: Symbol, Value <: AnyRef, Y <: HList, A <: Product](a : A)
                       (implicit 
                        gen : LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, FieldType[Key, Value] :: Y],
                        witness: shapeless.Witness.Aux[Key]) = {
    val aGen = gen.to(a).head
    (getFieldName(aGen), getFieldValue(aGen))
  }
```

But it throws this exception:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter gen: shapeless.LabelledGeneric.Aux[Ex,shapeless.labelled.FieldType[Key,Value] :: Y]
```

I'd like to call it like this:

```
scala> case class Ex(i: Int, ii: Int)
scala> val ex = Ex(1,2)
scala> getFieldNameValue(ex)
res1: (String, Int) = (i,1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This variant works:

```
  def getFieldNameValue[A <: Product, Repr <: HList,
                        K <: Symbol, V, T <: HList](a: A)(implicit 
    gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, Repr],
    ev: Repr <:< (FieldType[K, V] :: T),
    witness: Witness.Aux[K]): (String, V) = {
    val record: Repr = gen.to(a)
    (witness.value.name, record.head)
  }

  getFieldNameValue(ex) // (i,1)
```

I guess the trouble was that you tried to do too much work in one step (implicits don't like that).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked perfect. Could you explain what `ev: Repr <:< (FieldType[K, V] :: T)` does and why needed?

Comment: @jamborta `ev: X <:< Y` is an evidence (or proof) of the fact that `X` is a subtype of `Y`. If `Repr <: (FieldType[K, V] :: T)` were in generics section this wouldn't work but `Repr <:< (FieldType[K, V] :: T)` in implicits section did. The thing is that type inference and implicit resolution are two connected but different processes. And sometimes things that can't be inferred can be just checked after inference.